# Azure Function Python - serviceBusTrigger - How to deadletter a message

Tags: python, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a plain simple Python function which should dead-letter a message if it does not match few constraint. Actually I'm raising an exception and everything works fine (I mean the message is being dead-lettered), but I would like to understand if there is a "clean" way to dead-letter the message without raising an exception.

```
async def function_handler(message: func.ServiceBusMessage, starter: str):
    for msg in [message]:
        client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
        message_body = msg.get_body().decode("utf-8")

        msg = json.loads(message_body)

        if 'valid' in msg:    
           instance_id = await client.start_new('orchestrator', None, json.dumps(message_body))
        else:
           raise Exception(f'not found valid {msg["id"]}')
```

This is part of `host.json`, this should indicate I'm working with version 2.0 of Azure Functions

```
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
```

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: You can set the max delivery count to 1 and set the property on queue to deadletter the message when delivery count reaches the maximum. You will also need to set auto complete to false so that the message is not automatically deleted by Function runtime. Will this approach work?

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for the suggestion, but the question is how to "set the property on queue to deadletter "

Comment: You can do it through Azure Portal I believe.

Comment: I mean how to dead-letter the message, instead of raising an exception.

Comment: You don’t have to do anything. Service Bus will take care of it. Let me add my thoughts as answer and you can give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of writing, in Python it is **not** possible interactively send a message in dead-letter.

I found out that [autocomplete=false is only supported for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python#configuration).

This basically means that the only way to dead letter a message is raise an exception, just like I was doing in my code.

Thanks to @GauravMantri to pointing me the right way (i.e. have a look at how to use the autocomplete configuration parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus Queue has this `Max Delivery Count` property that you can make use of. Considering you only want to process a message exactly once and then deadletter the message in case Function is unable to process, what you can do is set the max delivery count to 1. That way the message will be automatically deadlettered after 1st delivery.

By default, Function runtime tries to auto-complete the message if there is no exception in processing the message. You do not want Function runtime to do that. For that what you would need to do is set `auto complete` setting to false. However if the message is processed successfully, you would want to delete that message thus you will need to call auto complete manually if the message processing is successful.

Something like:

```
if 'valid' in msg:    
    instance_id = await client.start_new('orchestrator', None, json.dumps(message_body))
    //auto complete the message here...
else:
    //do nothing and the message will be dead-lettered
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still it is not clear how to auto complete, could you please add a piece of code that explain? To be clear, looking at azure documentation I wasn't able to understand how. I'm not sure that it is possibile. It seems that Python implementation lacks of this part.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Python SDK for Azure Service Bus but there's a method called `complete_message` that you can use. Please see this for more details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/9eb1655fdcbdf69a5071872acc8316d71b17c3fd/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/_servicebus_receiver.py#L736. HTH.

Comment: I see. Well, in any case thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I found out that it is not possibile. I've just answered my own question.